# How to pass a instance variable from one extension to another extension?

Tags: apex

I would like to understand better how to pass the value of an instance variable from one extension to another extension.

**Good to know:** Visualforce pages are either A and B. 
Standard extensions are either 1 and 2.

1. I have a Visualforce page (A) that overrides the standard 'New'
   button for the Opportunity object.
2. This Visualforce page (A) references a commandbutton action that
   calls an extension (1).
3. That extension (1) in turns directs the user to a Visualforce page
   (B) for the Contract object.
4. This Visualforce page (B) references a commandbutton action which
   calls another extension (2).

I need an instance variable from extension (1) to be passed to extension (2). What is the best design pattern to follow to achieve this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the StandardController differs between each page, you'll have to pass the value somehow. You can choose to use a [Cookie](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites_cookie.htm) to store the value temporarily, or you can pass the value as a URL parameter on the [PageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_system_pagereference.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Either make a Wizard, or put it as a URL parameter.